# I need help completing my code. Note I am a beginner in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a script which sends an email about checking ping regularly at one hour interval of time. I am using Python to program this script and I cannot create a log file to keep the ping logs which I need to mail. I'm new to using subprocess module and its functions.

```
import threading
import os

def check_ping():
    threading.Timer(5.0, check_ping).start()
    hostname = "www.google.com"
    response = os.system("ping -c 4 " + hostname)

'''
def trace_route():
    threading.Timer(5.0, trace_route).start()
    hostname = "www.google.com"
    response = os.system("traceroute" + hostname)
'''
check_ping()
#trace_route()

output = check_ping()
file = open("sample.txt","a")
file.write(output)
file.close()




import os, platform
import threading

def check_ping():
    threading.Timer(10.0,check_ping).start()
    hostname = "www.google.com"
    response = os.system("ping " + ("-n 1 " if  platform.system().lower()=="windows" else "-c 1 ") + hostname)
    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Network Active"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Network Error"

    return pingstatus

pingstatus = check_ping()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having right now? What is the intended behaviour of your code, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Which of the two scripts you posted is the one we are talking about? I guess the first one?

Comment: In your second script, you don't write anything to any file, and in your first script, you don't return anything from the function, so you write nothing to the file.

Comment: @Finomnis Thanks for the reply. I want to make a document that can be used as a attachment for the mail containing the ping information. For this, I am not being able to create a file that can store the output that is provided by the above function.

Comment: For the second script, am i heading in right direction for creation of file to store the output that the function provides?

Comment: Not really. I understand that you do `threading.Timer` because just having a loop with a sleep is not precise enough for you? Also, it's a very javascript-y construct, but not wrong. What is wrong is that you return something. As your function will be called by the `threading.Timer`, the return value will never be used for anything. Just write to the file directly in your `check_ping` function.

Comment: Also, you are correct that using subprocess would be better, as you can hide the ping output with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

- using subprocess instead of os.system
- added timeout of 8 seconds
- writing to csv file instead of txt file
- added timestamps to csv file, without which I don't really see the point of logging in the first place

```
import os
import threading
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def check_ping():
    threading.Timer(10.0,check_ping).start()

    # Get current time
    timestamp = int(time.time())

    # Build the command
    hostname = "www.google.com"
    if os.name == 'nt':
        command = ['ping', '-n', '1', hostname]
    else:
        command = ['ping', '-c', '1', hostname]

    # Create process
    pingProcess = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    try:
        # Timeout 8 seconds, to avoid overlap with the next ping command
        outs, errs = pingProcess.communicate(timeout=8)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        # If timed out, kill
        pingProcess.kill()
        outs, errs = pingProcess.communicate()

    # Get the return code of the process
    response = pingProcess.returncode

    # and then check the response...
    # These four lines can be removed, they are just to see if the system
    # works.
    if response == 0:
        print("Network Active")
    else:
        print("Network Error")

    # You most likely want a CSV file, as most programs accept this file type,
    # including Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc
    # Further, I'm sure you want timestamps with the results.
    file = open("ping.csv","a")
    file.write(str(timestamp) + "," + str(response) + "\n")
    file.close()

check_ping()
```

---

Here is another version without using the system's `ping` command, but instead using a python library for pinging. This ensures that the code works on all operating systems:

```
import threading
import time

from ping3 import ping

def check_ping():
    threading.Timer(10.0,check_ping).start()

    # Get current time
    timestamp = int(time.time())

    # Build the command
    hostname = "www.google.com"

    # Run ping
    ping_result = ping(hostname, timeout=8)
    ping_success = False if ping_result is None else True

    # and then check the response...
    # These four lines can be removed, they are just to see if the system
    # works.
    if ping_success:
        print("Network Active (" + str(ping_result) + ")")
    else:
        print("Network Error")

    # You most likely want a CSV file, as most programs accept this file type,
    # including Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc
    # Further, I'm sure you want timestamps with the results.
    file = open("ping.csv", "a")
    ping_value_str = str(ping_result) if ping_success else "NaN"
    file.write(str(timestamp) + "," + ("0" if ping_success else "1") + "," + ping_value_str + "\n")
    file.close()

check_ping()
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It worked out pretty well and did the work perfectly that I wanted to be done although some of the codes used are complex for me to understand right now like the use of exceptions :D.

Comment: It's actually quite simple. If an exception is thrown, it propagates through the call stack until it hits a `try`. `pingProcess.communicate` throws the `TimeoutExpired` exception if it takes longer than its given timeout, in this case 8 seconds. It then gets caught by the `try`-`except` clause, executing the `pingProcess.kill()`.
If you look into tutorials about exceptions, it shouldn't take you more than 15 minutes to understand.

Comment: If you have more questions regarding the code, just ask.

Comment: You have been a good-willed guide for me and i thank you for that Sir. Yes I do have some queries about the code which I am trying to understand. The first one is: the need of time module for this code and does 'nt' represents the window support or anything else besides that?

Comment: Second one: What magic does using 'subprocess' module do that 'os' module doesn't regarding this code and the use of 'err, out'.

Comment: 1. time module: it's used in `timestamp = int(time.time())`; 2.: when subprocess is created with the =PIPE flags, it redirects stdout and stderr to its internal memory. when calling communicate, it then returns the stdout and stderr. So if you want to see what the ping process actually displayed, you can see it in the `outs` and `errs` variables. Otherwise, you can just remove them.

Comment: Further, I just realized that os.name == 'nt' is insufficient to detect whether the current operating system is windows. Therefore, if you really want to ensure operating system compatibility, you might switch to some pure python library that doesn't call the system's ping command, like [ping3](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3)